# Is this stucture an array of structs?

Tags: c, types, struct, declaration

```
struct SOutputQuantity
{
  TAnalogOutputQuantity outputQuantity;
  TValueType valueType;
};

static struct SOutputQuantity _outputTypeToQuantityMap[] = {

{,},
{,},

};
```

This is a beginner's question but I have tried to understand the code but can't get it. What I don't understand from this code is, if this is an array of structures then why there is keyword struct before it?

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to address what you're asking. A future reader here will not find "can you please explain following code" useful in a search result.

Comment: `struct` *name* is either a definition of a structure or a reference to one.  `struct a` and `struct b` are identifiers to specific types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always declare if something is a struct even if you have declared it before. it doesnt make a difference in the output of the program.

Comment: that means i can write: 

struct struct structure_name
{

};
but what sense it make?
and you want to say that it won't make any difference if i cancel "struct" keyword in static struct SOutputQuantity _outputTypeToQuantityMap[] line

Comment: well you don't declare  int int int int a = 4;

Comment: but since SOutputQuantity is a struct by definition... the proper way of declaring it is by adding the struct before it. but you can also leave it off.

Comment: but int int int a = 4; din't compile

Comment: like I said double declaration doesnt work. struct struct won't work either. but struct is something you define at the top of your program is not embedded in the c language that is why you can call an already defined struct (by you).struct SOutputQuantity.

Answer (score 1):

C declarations can be difficult to understand without some practice.  In the following, I'm ignoring some difficulties to do with pointers.  There are lots of good references online that explain in more detail how C declarations work.  That said, here's a simplified version of how to understand the code you give.

First, how do you declare an array `a` of `N` elements of some type `T`?  In C, this is written as

```
T a[N];
```

Note that `T` is the type of the elements of A.  This is true no matter what `T` is.  For example,

```
int a[N];
char a[N];
```

In each case, the type of the array element comes first on the declaration.  This is *also* true for structure types.  Ie,

```
struct foo a[N];
```

declares an array `a` of `N` elements, each of which is a `struct foo`.  In this case, unlike the previous two examples, there must be a definition of `struct foo` somewhere previously in source file or one of the included headers.

So, using the types from your example, the code

```
struct SOutputQuantity { /* ... */ };
static struct SOutputQuantity _outputTypeToQuantityMap[N];
```

declares `_outputTypeToQuantityMap` to be an array of N `SOutputQuantity` structures.

Quite rightly, you'll point out that this isn't *identical* to the code you showed. The final thing you're running into here is the concept of an *initializer*.  Suppose you want to declare an array of 3 integers, and initialize that array at compile time.  The syntax is

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

The compiler arranges (somehow, it doesn't really matter) that

```
a[0] == 1
a[1] == 2
a[2] == 3
```

before your program starts execution.  Next, when you have an initializer for an arra declaration, you can leave out the number of elements in the array, because the compiler can figure it out.  So,

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

is identical to the previous declaration.

So now, the last few lines of your example code can be understood as

```
struct SOutputQuantity _outputTypeToQuantityMap[] = {
    /* constant #1 */,
    /* constant #2 */,
};
```

This code is declaring and initializing a two-element array.  The only part left to understand is what `{,}` means.  This is rather confusing on its own, and its the result of a sequence of shortcuts C makes available.  Let's start without the array (and a simpler struct, so I don't have to type as much).

```
struct foo { int a; int b; };
struct foo x = { 1, 2 };
```

The second line of the above example declares and initializes a variable `f` of type `struct foo` so that

```
x.a == 1
x.b == 2
```

C allows you to omit omit trailing struct members from an initializer, filling in omitted values with zero.  In particular, you can omit *all* struct members.

```
struct foo x = { 1 };       // x.a == 1; x.b == 0
struct foo x = { };         // x.a == 0; x.b == 0
```

Finally, C allows you to include a trailing comma after the last initializer:

```
struct foo x = { 1, 2, };   // x.a == 1; x.b == 2
struct foo x = { 1, };      // x.a == 1; x.b == 0
```

I'm not sure if it's allowed by the standard, but it appears that your compiler also allows

```
struct foo x = { , };       // x.a == 0; x.b == 0
```

So, after all that,

```
static struct SOutputQuantity _outputTypeToQuantityMap[] = {
  {,},
  {,},
};
```

declares a 2-element array with each element of type `struct SOutputQuantity` and simultaneously initializes each element of that array so that the `outputQuantity` and `valueType` fields are initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct SOutputQuantity  // Line 1: defines "struct SOutputQuantity"
{
  TAnalogOutputQuantity outputQuantity;
  TValueType valueType;
};

static struct SOutputQuantity _outputTypeToQuantityMap[] = {  // Line 7: declars an array of SOutputQunantity    
  {,},
  {,}
};
```

1) Line 1 defines a "struct" (a complex data record) that you can use later in your program.

2) You don't show how TAnalogOutputQuantity and TValueType are defined - they're probably in a "typedef" somehere else (possibly in a .hr header file).

3) You they declare a variable named "_outputTypeToQuantityMap".

4) "_outputTypeToQuantityMap" is an array of SOutputQuantity.

5) The "static" means that the name "_outputTypeToQuantityMap" is visible only in this module.

6) "{,}" is apparently intended to initialze two elements, each consisting of an outputQuantity and a valueType.

Q: Does the code snippet even compile?